# Can't make a loop to fill nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some nan values. For this problem, i make a decision to fill that nan values with the average, but the problem is that i can't make a loop for that. I need to do a loop because i have 90 features to fill and each feature has its own average. Every possibilits that i have in my mind give's me:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Summarizing: I need the first average to be for the first variable. The second average for the second, so successively.

i did a functions, used lambda and loops (for). But, none than solve my problem. I don't know if is my logic that is't correct or if have a function specifies for this.

Comment: It would help if you shared some more information like the functions you tried.

Comment: Seems like one of your columns contains ints, but the average of that column is a float, so you'll need to provide an integer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need loops you can use the fact that fillna accepts a dict with the column names as keys as argument. Furthermore as @aaossa said you need to take into account that the average of integers is not necessarily an integer. Here I have downcasted via round, but other options are also viable depending on your context.

```
means = df.mean()
int_cols = df.dtypes.apply(pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype)
means.loc[int_cols] = means.loc[int_cols].round()
df = df.fillna(means.to_dict())
```